# Iterating through a Multidimensional associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I would like to iterate through the following array(This is the output when I print_r):

```
Array ( 
    [GetRecentCasesResult] => Array ( 
        [CaseHistory] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00305-Q0S7Y5 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 11:00:09 AM 
                [faultType] => Repair Blocked Sewer - Small Pipes 
                [status] => Open 
            ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00308-W4F8F0 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 01:17:04 PM 
                [faultType] => Repair Pothole in Major Road 
                [status] => Open 
            ) 
            [2] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00309-T8B2J6 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 01:44:38 PM 
                [faultType] => Repair Pothole in Major Road 
                [status] => Open 
            ) 
            [3] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00311-K7H8D9 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 02:18:29 PM 
                [faultType] => Electricity outage - Business 
                [status] => Open 
            ) 
            [4] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00303-C8M0K8 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 10:14:45 AM 
                [faultType] => Electricity outage - Business 
                [status] => Open 
            ) 
            [5] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00306-R7W8S7 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 11:14:40 AM 
                [faultType] => Animal Carcass Removal 
                [status] => Open 
            ) 
            [6] => Array ( 
                [caseNumber] => CAS-00307-B5Q6C0 
                [dateCreated] => 2016-01-17 11:17:22 AM 
                [faultType] => Water Leak 
                [status] => Open
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

I tried the following code:

```
foreach ($result as $firtsone) {
foreach ($firtsone as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.": ".$value;
}
}
```

and this is the error I am getting:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\emgtsz\faulth.php on line 30
>   CaseHistory: Array

Please assist.

Comment: As notice states `$value` is not always a string, sometimes it's array. Check with `is_array` for example.

Comment: as per example, $value is always an array, so u need to add one more loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

> and this is the result I am getting: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\emgtsz\faulth.php on line 30 CaseHistory: Array

That's because `$value` will not always be a string, it might be an array.

**Solution:**

Recursively iterate the array and print the (key, value) pairs, like this:

```
function process_array($array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            process_array($value);
        }else{
            echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
        }
    }
}

process_array($result);
```

**Edited:**

> how would I display these as table instead of one after another ?

Use the iterative approach, like this:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Case Number</th>";
echo "<th>Date Created</th>";
echo "<th>Fault Type</th>";
echo "<th>status</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$arrayLength = count($result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory']);
for($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; ++$i){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'][$i]['caseNumber'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'][$i]['dateCreated'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'][$i]['faultType'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'][$i]['status'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: @devpro I've edited the question. See the array now.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, how would I display these as table instead of one after another ?

Comment: @kya If you want to display them in table cells, then iterative way would be a good approach. See the **edited** section of my answer.